# Process access rights seem to differ when run from the compiler and as a standalone exe

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder, handle, openprocess

I am using WINAPI for a program that I am writing. The program has the ProcessId of another process and needs to get a handle of it (to be able to terminate it later, and also to periodically check if the process is alive and responding by using WaitForSingleObject). When I compile my program (in Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010 C++ Builder), it works well; the program seems to get the handle successfully and generally works as intended. However, if I launch it from the folder as a standalone exe, it seems to fail to get the handle properly. I checked it by comparing (Companion is a HANDLE and Companion_PID is a DWORD):

```
GetProcessId(Companion)
```

and

```
Companion_PID
```

Where, a few lines earlier, Companion is taken from Companion_PID in the following code:

```
Companion = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, Companion_PID);
```

And the "GetProcessId(Companion)" results in 0 (which is a good sign that the OpenProcess failed to return a proper handle.

I'm pretty surprised that this code works differently when run from the compiler and as a standalone exe; I'm assuming in the first case the security attributes are inherited from the compiler itself, but I'd like to hear a possibly better explanation for this behaviour from someone more experienced in WINAPI and security attributes in particular.

Small update: yes, like I thought, OpenProcess results in error 0x5 = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [OpenProcess function page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN:

> To open a handle to another local process and obtain full access
>   rights, you must enable the SeDebugPrivilege privilege.

I believe your IDE (you're running your application from *IDE*, not from *compiler*) has `SeDebugPrivilege` enabled by default. When you run your application, your IDE (process) is creating a new process which inherits privileges from IDE, including `SeDebugPrivilege` and that's the reason why function succeeds when run from IDE.

Your application should check whether it has `SeDebugPrivilege` enabled, and if not, [enable it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Also, IDE is probably running as admin.  Non-admin processes generally don't have SeDebugPrivilege in their token at all.

Comment: I agree, found that VS2010 has this privilege enabled when run as Admin: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/682623/sedebugprivilege-enabled-during-ide-debug-session

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be exactly the case. Will dig into this. And yes, I meant IDE; English isn't my native language and I mess the definitions a bit sometimes.

Comment: A question though; if the process I'm trying to get the handle of is also mine (I can re-write it with modifications), and I need only to Terminate it and Synchronize with it (WaitForSingleObject), do I still need to enable the SeDebugPrivilege, or I can set the security attributes of that process so that it will let my second program get its handle?

Comment: `OpenProcess()` requires `SeDebugPrivilege`. You must set it and it's easy. Have a look here how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446619(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Ok, will do. The reason of my question was just because I thought of the following variant (if p1 is my process and p2 is the process that I was trying to open in it): p2 executes GetCurrentProcess (pseudo-handle), DuplicateHandle ("converts" to real handle with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS rights), and sends this duplicated handle to my p1 process which later uses it when necessary.

Comment: That sounds complicate. Just use `OpenProcess()`. You can disable `SeDebugPrivilege` privilege once you've got the other process' handle.